# CentOS, Timeout: No Response in remote SNMP access

Tags: linux, remote-access, net-snmp

i have installed snmp, utils using

```
yum install net-snmp

yum install net-snmp-utils
```

This is my /etc/snmp/snmpd.config

```
syslocation System Location
syscontact email@a.com
#      sec.name   source          community (password) 
com2sec Mybox     localhost          public 
com2sec Outside   default            public 
#      group.name sec.model  sec.name 
group   RWGroup    v2c       Mybox 
group   ROGroup    v2c       Outside 
view all     included  .1        80 
view system  included  system    fe 
#              context sec.model sec.level prefix  read    write  notif 
access  ROGroup   ""      any    noauth    exact   all     none   none 
access  RWGroup   ""      v2c    noauth    exact   all     all    all
```

SNMP WALK works locally (localhost and 10.106.240.138-my static IP)

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.106.240.138:161
```

Whereas it doesnt work from a remote Linux system (say 10.106.240.179 - same network)

`Timeout: No Response from 10.106.240.138:161`

iptables,ip6tables(firewall) have been disbaled

I have tried with a simpler snmpd.conf configuration too !

`rocommunity public
syslocation "EARTH"
syscontact user@domain.com`

Help me! what am I missing !!

## EDIT 1

Hi, i found the /etc/sysconfig/snmp file and added the OPTIONS config to it to allow my SNMP client IP

`OPTIONS="-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a -x 10.106.240.179"`

It still doesnt work !

This is my SNMP service status

`snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2014-09-05 02:47:42 IST; 5s ago
 Main PID: 21847 (snmpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snmpd.service
           └─21847 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a -x 10.106.240.179 -f`

Any input would be appreciated, thanks !

Do I have to configure the remote client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the daemon is not listening on localhost only.
This should be specified in /etc/sysconfig/snmpd.options (I don't remember exactly).

Comment: Hi unlink, i have made the changes and updated the question, pls let me know if you can figure out any problem? Thanks!

Comment: You configured the server to listen on the client IP address: OPTIONS="-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a -x 10.106.240.179". Change the line to the server address: OPTIONS="-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a -x 10.106.240.138" or completely remove the -x option.

Comment: i uncommented the line ` OPTIONS="-LS0-6d -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid"` but it still does not work. however it does work locally only.